# Python: Better way/module to manipulate image quality

Tags: python, image, graphics

What can you advise me to use to manipulate images using python? So long for now I consider GD and Image libraries.

Sultan

Comment: Could you explain which shortcomings that you've experienced with either GD or PIL (Image module)? i.e. why are you looking for another option?

Comment: I'm using WebKit browser API to make web site screenshots so sometimes the image size grows up to ~5MB and more

Comment: Ok, and why is PIL not good enough for your needs?

Comment: @gab The reason is that I've VPS with server limited memory params )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). Easy to understand with good [documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm).

What they say about themselves:

> The Python Imaging Library adds image processing capabilities to your Python interpreter.
>
> This library provides extensive file format support, an efficient internal representation, and fairly powerful image processing capabilities.
>
> The core image library is designed for fast access to data stored in a few basic pixel formats. It should provide a solid foundation for a general image processing tool.

Cheers

Comment: He was looking for an alternative to GD or Image -- and the Image module is the base module of PIL.